# Open browser through server

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, jira

I am running a linux server (not specific flavor, as the place I work has their own custom flavor). I have 2 set up, one running MySQL server, and the other running Jira. What I would like to do is connect the two so I can start doing some Jira development. My current problem is the server that has Jira on I have to SSH into, and it says I can access Jira at Localhost8080 (pretty normal) but I dont have a way to open a browser through the command line, and I am still very new to console/SSH. Is there a way to access the jira instance from my desktop(mac)? Or is there a way to launch a browser window through my server that I SSH into?

Comment: why not configure jira to listen to external ips? then it'd be `http://ip.of.jiramachine:8080`

Comment: Or maybe you can install a terminal browser, like `lynx`.. http://www.tecmint.com/command-line-web-browsers/

Comment: @Hackerman lynx doesn't support JavaScript. JIRA's http interface uses it extensively, so they're not really a good fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSH Forwarding is your answer. When you're done, you'll have your JIRA page open in Safari on your MAC, and you'll have your ssh client silently maintaining the connection for you in the background.

You want to look here:

http://manas.tungare.name/blog/ssh-port-forwarding-on-mac-os-x/

On step 2 where it shows this part:

2. -L local_port:service_host:service_port \

you're going to add something like `-L 8081:localhost:8080 \`

The other options are plain ssh; if you connect to ssh on your server on a port other than 22, you need the `3.` part, otherwise you can skip that line.

To get it working the first time, I would skip `4.` and `5.` as well, making your (one line) command look something like this:

`ssh -L 8081:localhost:8080 yourJIRAServerNameHere`

You have to run this at the terminal. It will give you a text-based interface to log in. The port forward won't be active until you authenticate.

Then you'll open Safari up to localhost:8081 and see your JIRA site

(We specified port 8081 in the ssh command and it will default to the 'localhost' adapter)

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly. Thank you very much! I really appreciate it!